# Como mudar todos os valores de um array JSON?

Tags: javascript

```
var cookie = [
{"domain":".nada.com","flag":true,"expiration":"1595998766"},
{"domain":".nada.com","flag":true,"expiration":"1627534734"},
{"domain":".nada.com","flag":true,"expiration":"1595998765"}
]
```

// Mudar os valores das chaves expiration para 0 todas
// Ex.

```
[
{"domain":".nada.com","flag":true,"expiration":"0"},
{"domain":".nada.com","flag":true,"expiration":"0"},
{"domain":".nada.com","flag":true,"expiration":"0"}
]
```

Comment: `cookie.forEach((el) => el.expiration = 0)`

Comment: @MarceloBoni poderia postar como uma resposta esta solução :)

Comment: @MarceloBoni se possível poderia postar um exemplo mano

Answer (score 2):

Existem algumas maneiras de se fazer isso, mas a que eu recomendo é o uso de `Array.prototype.forEach()`[¹](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var cookie = [{
    "domain": ".nada.com",
    "flag": true,
    "expiration": "1595998766"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".nada.com",
    "flag": true,
    "expiration": "1627534734"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".nada.com",
    "flag": true,
    "expiration": "1595998765"
  }
];

cookie.forEach((el) => el.expiration = 0);

console.log(cookie);
```

Com isso você altera o array inicial, o forEach percorre cada elemento do array com isso você não tem que se preocupar com o index do elemento atual, apesar de ser possível utiliza-lo com a sintaxe `.forEach((el, index) => console.log(index))`.

Caso você queira percorrer o array e ainda assim manter o valor original do antigo array para algo em especifico, você pode usar o `Array.prototype.map()`[²](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) da seguinte forma:

```js
var cookie = [{
    "domain": ".nada.com",
    "flag": true,
    "expiration": "1595998766"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".nada.com",
    "flag": true,
    "expiration": "1627534734"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".nada.com",
    "flag": true,
    "expiration": "1595998765"
  }
];

var newCookie = cookie.map((el) => {
  return { ...el, expiration: 0 }
});

console.log(cookie);
console.log(newCookie);
```

A magica está no uso do *spread operator (...)[³](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)* nessa linha: `{...el, expiration: 0}`. Desse modo pegamos todo conteúdo original do array e sobrescrevemos o valor de `expiration` com 0.